# Prove that the dimension of the direct product of two vector spaces is the sum of their dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

How should I go about proving this?

How should I go about proving that the dimension of the direct product of two vector spaces is the sum of their dimensions?

$\dim (U \times W) = \dim U + \dim W$

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Tip: Try to make your question's title as descriptive as possible, ideally summarizing what you are asking.

Comment: i tried breaking the element (u,w) into their respective basis. like (u,w) = ((a1u1+...+anun), (b1w1+...+bnwn))

Comment: @titi1975 If you are satisfied with my answer below, please accept it by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> i tried breaking the element (u,w) into their respective basis. like (u,w) = ((a1u1+...+anun), (b1w1+...+bnwn))

That is the basic idea.

We will prove that if $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ is a basis for $U$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ is a basis for $W$, then $\{(u_1,0),(0,w_1),\dots,(u_n,0),(0,w_m)\}$ is a basis for $U\times W$.

Let $x\in U\times W$, then $x=(u,w)$ for some $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Note that
\begin{align}
x&=(u,w)=(a_1u_1+\cdots+a_nu_n,b_1w_1+\cdots+b_mw_m)\\
&=a_1(u_1,0)+b_1(0,w_1)+\cdots+a_n(u_n,0)+b_m(0,w_m).
\end{align}
Therefore, the set $\{(u_1,0),(0,w_1),\dots,(u_n,0),(0,w_m)\}$ spans $U\times W$.

I will leave it up to you to prove that $\{(u_1,0),(0,w_1),\dots,(u_n,0),(0,w_m)\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Finally, since $\{(u_1,0),(0,w_1),\dots,(u_n,0),(0,w_m)\}$ is a basis for $U\times W$, we can conclude that $$\dim(U\times W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W).$$